# How can I start dired in omit mode?

Tags: dired

I use the following code for including dired omit mode:

```
(require 'dired-x)
(setq dired-omit-files "^\\...+$")
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (dired-omit-mode 1)))
;(dired-omit-mode 1)
```

When I turn on dired, by `(C-x d)`, text files ending with ~ are visible. I can hide them by hitting `M-x dired-omit-mode`. However I would like that dired opens directly into omit mode. I try to achieve this by uncommenting the fourth line, (dired-omit-mode 1), but I get the error message:

```
Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

What is wrong with my forth code line?

How to start dired in omit mode?

Comment: `C-h f dired-omit-mode` tells you: "If called from Lisp, enable
the mode if `ARG` is omitted or nil."

Comment: @Drew: yes, I read the same from C-h f, but I have no clue as to which consequences this have on how to alter my code.

Answer (score 5):

Dired-Omit mode is a buffer-local minor mode, it doesn't make sense if the current buffer is not a Dired buffer, thus the following doesn't make sense because when Emacs starts the current buffer is definitely not a Dired buffer (actually it's in Fundamental mode):

```el
;;; init.el
(dired-omit-mode 1)
```

The correct way to enable `dired-omit-mode` whenever Dired starts is using `dired-mode-hook`, e.g.,

```el
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'dired-omit-mode)
```

The following does the same as the above but is verbose

```el
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (dired-omit-mode 1)))
```

And since `dired-omit-mode` is provided by `dired-x.el` and isn't autoloaded (though I think it is worth to be autoloaded), you won't be able to invoke `dired-omit-mode` unless it's defined or autoloaded. You can autoload it via

```el
(autoload 'dired-omit-mode "dired-x")
```

or you can ensure it's defined via

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'dired
  (require 'dired-x))
```

the following does the similar as the above, though it will slow down your Emacs startup

```el
(require 'dired-x)
```

I'm not sure what's the problem you're encountering, but if you understand the code you're using, it's likely you can fix it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to insert your (autoload 'dired-omit-mode "dired-x")  between my first and second code line, between my second and third line, and below my third line. In none of these positions did dired start in omit mode. How would you alter my code in order to make it open dired in omit mode?

Comment: @myotis `(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'dired-omit-mode)` does the work, if it doesn't for you, you have to try to figure out what it does and why by yourself, since I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: This worked for me also. Needed to reset emacs before the add hook worked. Thanks.